# Linked List Data access

Tags: c++, linked-list, binary-search-tree, singly-linked-list

In C++ if I have a Binary Search Tree (BST) of the following form

```
Struct node{ 
 node leftChild; 
 node rightChild; 
 int data;}
```

Is it legal to access leftChild Data like this:

```
foo (node head)
    {
    std::cout << head.leftChild.data; 
    }
```

Also, sometimes I see linked list nodes use *node for the children and other times they just use node. When/why would you use either. Sorry for the string question just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because you cannot have a structure like that. It would be infinitely large (a `node` has two child `node`s, each of which have two child `node`s, etc. forever). This is exactly why people will use pointers when making a node that has children of the same type.

For example, how **not** to do it:

```
/* This is a problem because of the recursive nature of the structure. leftChild also
contains a leftChild itself, which also contains a leftChild, etc. forever. */
struct node
{ 
    node leftChild; // how big is leftChild? infinitely large!
    node rightChild; // how big is rightChild? infinitely large!
    int data;
}
```

And the **right** way to do it:

```
/* This is not a problem because the size of a pointer is always 4 bytes (assuming 32-
bit system). You can allocate room for the child nodes without recursively requiring an
infinite amount of memory. */
struct node
{ 
    node* leftChild; // how big is leftChild? 4 bytes (assuming 32-bit system)
    node* rightChild; // how big is rightChild? 4 bytes (assuming 32-bit system)
    int data;
}
```

Once you do it the right way, it's totally legal to say:

```
void foo(node head)
{
    std::cout << head.leftChild->data; // assuming leftChild points to a valid object!
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I was under that impression but was second guessing myself with the help of some friends. So if I change the structure to 
Struct node{node* left; node* right; int data} can I then say head->left->data

Comment: @SeanDunford: Yes, that's correct. (assuming `head` is a pointer)

Comment: Sweet. The books I am looking at have a mix of java and C++ so maybe I was mistaken on the language the node struct was written in. OR I just made up the idea that I saw it like before...drugs are bad mmmmkay. Thanks again.

Comment: @SeanDunford: In Java it's ok because Java works with reference semantics (that is, it's already using pointers under the covers). C++ is a bit different and prefers value semantics, so you've got to put the pointers in yourself.

Comment: Java is a super freak.. the kind you don't bring home to momma. 


I appreciate the insight.

Comment: @Cornstalks Java uses value semantics too, it's just those values are references.